# How to get a Batch Job session to push a zipped file from a remote server to a local machine/server

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-task-scheduler, windows-server-2016, remoteapp

I have a program that our clients run as a RemoteApp. This program copies files out of a folder to another folder, then zips those files and downloads/copies them off the remote server to the client's local machine or flash drive.

The big picture of what I am trying to achieve is to have the ability for the client to set up a schedule of when they want the files downloaded/copied to their machine out being logged into the RemoteApp.

I have created the interface in the RemoteApp to create a schedule and it then creates a task in Windows Task Scheduler for the program to be run and the files are copied, zipped, and downloaded/copied.

The task created is successful and is executed to completion when the zipped files are moved to a location on the server that Task Scheduler and the Program are on.

However, when the path to place the zipped files is on my local machine it fails because it can not access the path location when Task Scheduler is running the program. When the user creates a path to their local machine and runs the program in an Interactive Session the path is as follows:

\tsclient\C\Data Export files

As I understand it Task Schedule launches the program using a user's credentials in a Batch Job session. Is there any way to let this session connect to my local machine and move the zipped files? Do I need to specify the computer that I am moving the data to IP Address' or some other kind of Identifier in the file path?

Comment: Having run into similar issues, and for security reasons, setting up Secure File Transfer and using puTTY to automate that transfer was chosen. One minor issue I found was that clocks on the two machines had to be synchronized within ~10 minutes, or connection failed (one PC did not use a time service to set its clock - ever).

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Is Secure FIle Transfer a program or a protocol? I looked up puTTY and that seems to be a solution for a lot of applications, however, we are looking for a solution that does not require us to manage a client-side program to manage this process. Also, we have clients across the US and our servers are actually based on the West coast while our main office is on the East. So the ~10 min issue would make this not work as a solution for us. Again, I appreciate you responding to my post.

Comment: Time sync is UCT, so that is not an issue. If you want to explore SFTP with a GUI, install WinSCP and see if it meets your needs. The main advantage of SFTP is high security, better than FTP or over an unencrypted network.